# Trouble trying to output file using vtkOBJWriter

Tags: makefile, cmake, vtk

I am trying to use vtkOBJWriter from David Doria to convert a .vtk file to a .obj file. I git cloned from https://github.com/daviddoria/vtkOBJWriter, added a build directory for the CMake and make, and altered the file vtkOBJWriterExample.cxx to:

```
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkPolyData.h>
#include <vtkSphereSource.h>
#include <vtkPolyDataReader.h>

#include "vtkOBJWriter.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> input;
  std::string outputFilename;

  // Verify command line arguments
  if(argc > 1) // Use the command line arguments
    {
    if(argc != 3)
      {
      std::cout << "Required arguments: InputFilename.vtp OutputFilename.obj" << std::endl;
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataReader> reader =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataReader>::New();
    reader->SetFileName(argv[1]);
    reader->Update();

    input = reader->GetOutput();

    outputFilename = argv[2];

    }
  else
    {
    outputFilename = "output.obj";
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkSphereSource> sphereSource =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkSphereSource>::New();
    sphereSource->Update();
    input->ShallowCopy(sphereSource->GetOutput());
    }

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkOBJWriter> writer = 
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkOBJWriter>::New();

  writer->SetInput(input);
  writer->SetFileName(outputFilename.c_str());
  writer->Update();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

to reflect that I am using VTK 5.8.0 . When I try to do sudo ./vtkOBJWriterExample trytry1.vtk Documents/comeOn.obj , no output file is made (I don't see it in the appropriate directory). I also tried it with trytry1.vtp, and it didn't seem to work. My vtk file format is :

```
# vtk DataFile Version 3.0
vtk output
ASCII
DATASET POLYDATA
FIELD FieldData 3
group_id 1 1 int
0 
base_index 1 3 int
0 0 0 
avtOriginalBounds 1 6 double
-10 10 -10 10 -10 10 
POINTS 14387 float
-5.10204 -2.65306 -9.69246 -5.10204 -2.75294 -9.59184 -5.37199 -2.65306 -9.59184 

...

POLYGONS 28256 113024
3 0 1 2 

...

POINT_DATA 14387
SCALARS hardyglobal float
LOOKUP_TABLE default
3.4926 3.4926 3.4926 3.4926 3.4926 3.4926 3.4926 3.4926 3.4926 

...
```

which doesn't seem to match the formatting of car.vtp in the data directory, but I thought I made the appropriate changes (using the formatting of vtkPolyDataReader.h instead of vtkXMLPolyDataReader.h ). I am not sure why there is no file being outputted.

I do not receive any error messages.

Comment: I'm going to test this week, but : don't you have any error message ? do your program has rights to write in this dir var/www/labvtk/labvtk/ ? does it works when you want to write your data from a vtkSphereSource ?

Comment: Marcassin might be onto something - try running it from a different directory. And test with http://www.vtkedge.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/IO/WriteVTP to see if that produces an output file.  There should be no code path in either of these that does not write a file, so if you are looking in the right directory, it has to be something non-VTK causing your problem (like permissions, etc.)

Comment: Hi, it works now, thank you. It was a really dumb directory problem. my command line arguments were incorrect and should have just been something like sudo ./vtkOBJWriterExample trytry1.vtk comeOn.obj

Comment: @ThinkFlow Please add an answer explaining this instead of just a comment so we can accept it to "close" this question. Also, you should not need 'sudo' in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a directory problem (my command line arguments were pointing to the wrong directory). It should have been just ./vtkOBJWriterExample trytry1.vtk comeOn.obj